# creating an array of dictionaries from a plist in swift

Tags: swift

I'm very new to Swift (and can do basic Objective C but not much more than that). I have a plist of dictionaries and am trying to load it into an array. Here's my code:

```
            let resultArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)!
            var swiftArray = [Dictionary<String,String>]()
            for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.count; i++){
                swiftArray.addObject(resultArray.objectAtIndex(i))
            }
```

I know that `resultArray` is created correctly. The last line of this code, however, gives me the error `[(Dictionary<String,String>)] does not have a member named 'addObject'.`

How can I get these dictionaries loaded into `swiftArray`?

Thanks for your help, guys and gals.

Comment: You have an array. Why bother adding objects to a new array. Just use the array you already have.

Comment: Because I'm trying to work with Swift classes rather than Objective C classes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `append` method instead of `addObject`. Swift arrays don't have an `addObject` method.

```
swiftArray.append(resultArray.objectAtIndex(i) as Dictionary<String, String>)
```

Or simply convert the `NSArray` to a swift array

```
var swiftArray = resultArray as [AnyObject] as [Dictionary<String, String>]
```

Comment: I tried those, but I get a different error: `'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'Dictionary<String,String>'` for the first, and `'String' is not identical to 'Dictionary<String,String>'` for the second.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I had copied that from a part of my code and forgot to change all the types :) It should work now.

Comment: Thank you! That did it! But the array was big enough that it was REALLY slow to load—which means I have to learn how to deal with (dum, dum, DUM!) Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

Using Swift: I used a plist to store my array of dictionaries, loaded it up using an NSMutableArray. I show a way to get to the data below in the for loop.

```
// globals
var myArray = NSMutableArray()
var SamplePath = NSString()

SamplePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyFile", ofType: "plist")!
myArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: SamplePath as String)!

var i = 0 
for myElement in myArray {
    println(myArray[i]["Title"]as! String, myArray[i]["start"]as! Int, myArray[i]["detail"]as! String)
    i++
}
```

I created a temporary struct to load the value for an individual Dictionary when I need to do extra manipulation but simple things can be written directly into the array element using the setValue function of NSMutableArray:

```
myArray[Index].setValue(b, forKey:"Title").
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to exploit NSArray bridging with simply:

```
var swiftArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: file) as! [Dictionary<String,String>]
```

For example:

```
39> arNS
$R9: NSArray = "2 values" {
  [0] = 1 key/value pair {
    [0] = {
      0 = (instance_type = 0x0000000102002da0 )
      1 = (instance_type = 0x0000000000000003)
    }
  }
  [1] = 1 key/value pair {
    [0] = {
      0 = (instance_type = 0x00000001020060e0 )
      1 = (instance_type = 0x0000000000000003)
    }
  }
}

40> var arSW = arNS as! [[String:Int]] 
arSW: [[String : Int]] = 2 values {
  [0] = {
    [0] = {
      key = "abc"
      value = 1
    }
  }
  [1] = {
    [0] = {
      key = "xyz"
      value = 2
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I applaud you for getting away from NSArray.  If you find yourself needing to deal with NSArray methods in Swift, you might consider adding Swift Array extensions to implement the NSArray method but with immediate conversion to Array.